# Modeling a many-to-many relationship between 3 tables with Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following 3 entities:

- User
- Account
- Role

And the relationship goes like

- One user can have many accounts
- One account can belong to many users
- Each user has a role in an account
- There are a few, predefined roles (defined in the enum Roles)

I got this far:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

Every time an user registers, they also create an account, so I thought of this:

```
public async Task AddAccountAsync(User user, string accountName)
{
    Account account = new Account(user, accountName);
    Role role = new Role(Roles.Owner);
    Accounts.Add(account);
    user.Accounts.Add(account);
    Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await SaveChangesAsync();
 }
```

But I am not sure how to tie the role to the user to the account, so I can get the role an user has in an account.

For example:

Consider 3 users and 3 accounts:

- Account1 = (User1, Owner), (User2, TeamMember)
- Account2 = (User2, Owner)
- Account3 = (User3, Owner), (User1, ReadOnlyMember)

Following @IvanStoev's answer, I got this:

```
public async Task AddAccountAsync(User user, string accountName)
{
   Role role = new Role(Roles.Owner);
   Account account = new Account(model.AccountCurrency, model.AccountName, model.Description);
   UserAccount uc = new UserAccount
   {
       User = user,
       Account = account,
       Role = role
   };
   account.UserAccounts.Add(uc);
   Accounts.Add(account);

   user.UserAccounts.Add(uc);
   Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
   await SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Should I be saving the UserAccount object (as a `DbContext<UserAccount>`)?

Comment: Can a `User` have an `Account` without a `Role`? You should provide more details, if you provide an example of what you want, it would be better.

Comment: @TaherRahgooy No, users need a role in an account. I'll add an example

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> - One user can have many accounts
> - One account can belong to many users
> - Each user has a role in an account

The automatic link table does not work for scenarios like this when you need to associate additional information (`Role` in this case) with the `User - Account` link.

So instead of automatic `many-to-many` association you need to use two `one-to-many` associations with explicit link entity like this:

*Model:*

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class UserAccount
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

*Configuration:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
    .HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.AccountId });

modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.User)
    .WithMany(e => e.UserAccounts)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);

modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Account)
    .WithMany(e => e.UserAccounts)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.AccountId);

modelBuilder.Entity<UserAccount>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Role)
    .WithMany(e => e.UserAccounts)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.RoleId);
```

You can create a new `UserAccount` in a several ways.

One way is to add it to one of the child `UserAccounts` collections. In your example, `account.UserAccounts.Add(uc);` followed by `context.Accounts.Add(account)` will automatically add it to `context.UserAccounts`, `user.UserAccounts` and `role.UserAccounts`.

Another way is to use `context.UserAccounts.Add(uc);` in which case it will be automatically added to `user`, `account` and `role` child `UserAccounts` collections.

Comment: This seems pretty good. Could you please add an example of how would I then create new users/accounts? I have a guess but I want to make sure

Comment: It's enough to add the `UserAccount` to one of the child collections (like in usual `one-to-many` case). In your sample, `account.UserAccounts.Add(uc);` should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's what I was looking for