# Need a solution to reduce calls to the database with SQL Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sqlite

For example, I have multiple tables in my database SQLite. We have a business table and owner table because there could be more than one owner to a business.

Business

- Business ID
- Business Name
- Business Address
- Owner ID

Owner

- Owner ID
- Owner Phone Number
- Owner Address
- Business ID

So in my project I had to do make a call to the database to store my information for business table first and then make another call to the database to store owner information, because owner table needs the ID the business table generates first. This makes me have to make 2 calls to the database which will take more time.

In this example above, the time may not matter much, but I am looking for a solution if I were to have to make over 10+ calls to the database because each table needs data from another table therefor it must be stored first before we pull information from it.

Comment: Entity Framework allows you to save related data at once. Did you try :`var business = new Business { ..., Owner = new Owner { ..}}`

Comment: For many-to-many relationships use 3-table design. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553853/modeling-a-many-to-many-relationship-between-3-tables-with-code-first

Comment: For storing I think is no choice but to do all the query. You can make the insert inside transaction if you worried about consistency.

Comment: @Eldar I have not tried it yet, but if we were to have another table that contains the business employees which takes business ID as a foreign key, but its not related directly to the owner table. Would we still be able to save them together?

Comment: As long as you have the correct navigation properties and EF can decide the navigation chain (eg. no recursion) you can insert entities as a graph.